# Access to the path denied while uploading files

Tags: asp.net-ajax

I am going to upload an image with file upload control from the client and convert it in to a stream object and sending it to a wcf service, This process working with asp.net application but when I host this application in IIS 5.1  while upload the document it is showing error as

> Access to the path 'C:\Documents and Settings\patnayak\Desktop\Temp.xlsx' is denied

After Google search  I give access to asp.net user permissions to Temp.xlsx in my system then it is working. What about other Systems to upload a file.

My code:

```
            ClientBOL.CD.CPI2Library objLib = new ClientBOL.CD.CPI2Library();
            UDO.CPI2LibraryList libfiles = new UDO.CPI2LibraryList(true, "");

            HttpFileCollection hfc = Request.Files;
            libfiles.CPI2Libraries = new UDO.CPI2Library[hfc.Count];
            for (int i = 0; i < hfc.Count; i++)
            {
                HttpPostedFile hpf = hfc[i];
                if (hpf.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                                            libfiles.CPI2Libraries[i] = new UDO.CPI2Library();

                    libfiles.CPI2Libraries[i].FileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName);
                    libfiles.CPI2Libraries[i].FiletypeId = GetFileTypeId(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName));
                    libfiles.CPI2Libraries[i].DoctypeId = 1;
                                           FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(hpf.FileName);
                    UDO.UDOFileOperations.RemoteFileInfo ri = new UDO.UDOFileOperations.RemoteFileInfo();
                    System.IO.FileStream stream = new System.IO.FileStream(hpf.FileName, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read);
                                            ri.FileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName);
                    ri.Length = fileInfo.Length;
                    ri.FileByteStream = stream;
                    ClientBOL.CD.FileOperations cdc = new ClientBOL.CD.FileOperations();
                    cdc.UploadFile(ri);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not enough to grant permissions to just the file. IIS needs access to **ALL** of the directories leading up to the file.

e.g.  There could be a bag of diamonds just sitting on the floor, with your name on it, but if that floor is inside a locked bank vault, you can't go in there to pick it up.

Comment: Please let me know how which permissions have to give in iis 5.1

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error message. Check if the properties of folder uncheck readonly in General tab. In security Tab give write control for Network Service.

or

```
Add MachineName\IIS_IUSRS permission to the shared folder.
```

Hope this would work.